# MySQL: compare a mixed field containing letters and numbers

Tags: mysql

I have a field in the mysql database that contains data like the following:

```
    Q16
    Q32
    L16
    Q4
    L32
    L64
    Q64
    Q8
    L1
    L4
    Q1
```

And so forth. What I'm trying to do is pull out, let's say, all the values that start with Q which is easy:

```
field_name LIKE 'Q%'
```

But then I want to filter let's say all the values that have a number higher than 32. As a result I'm supposed to get only 'Q64', however, I also get Q4, Q8 and so for as I'm comparing them as strings so only 3 and the respective digit are compared and the numbers are in general taken as single digits, not as integers.
As this makes perfect sense, I'm struggling to find a solution on how to perform this operation without pulling all the data out of the database, stripping out the Qs and parsing it all to integers.

I did play around with the CAST operator, however, it only works if the value is stored as string AND it contains only digits. The parsing fails if there's another character in there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the number from the string and cast it to a number with `*1` or `cast`

```
select * from your_table
where substring(field_name, 1, 1) = 'Q'
and substring(field_name, 2) * 1 > 32
```